# Can we restore snapshot taken from 3 node cassandra cluster (RF is 2) in 1 node cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, restore, cassandra-3.0

I have 3 node Cassandra cluster in production with replication factor 2, currently, I am taking the snapshots of this production cluster using "nodetool snapshot" and copying all snapshot directory to s3.

Now I need to restore this snapshot backup on s3 to dev 1 node Cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can restore data from snapshot to a node using `sstableloader`.
Refer the link to know about `sstableloader` usage

> https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html